# deploy web application using tess4j in linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tess4j

i have to search in document stored in databases,among these documents is images,so i used tess4j to read this images.
 in windows with eclipse the project works fine with tess4j ,also if i deploy application in tomcat 6.35 in windows7 the projects works fine and i can search correctly with tess4j.
  sous windows
  1) i add the jar files in tomcat lib/shared
  2) the tessdata and dll file are in repository and i call them in the project.

in linux environment i do the same things and the first error that i get is

```
- Native library (linux-x86/libtesseract.so) not found in resource lib/shared/*
```

i add the libtesseract.so and the tessdata to this path and now i get an other error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate
    at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:208)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:199)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.TessBaseAPICreate(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at org.coin.bean.ged.Tess4j.extractTextFromImage(Tess4j.java:55)
    at org.coin.bean.ged.IndexDocument.CreateIndex(IndexDocument.java:158)
    at org.coin.bean.ged.searchlucene.setKeyword(searchlucene.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.coin.servlet.filter.PreventInjectionFilter.doFilter(PreventInjectionFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
- --Erroring: batchId[7] message[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate]

Comment: HI, did you solve the problem, I also have the same problem with Tess4j in Linux Centos. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting started with tess4j, but it looks like you may need to install "tesseract" first. i am betting it will copy the missing binaries into that directory.

[How does one install Tesseract-OCR 3.03 in Ubuntu/Linux distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213379/how-does-one-install-tesseract-ocr-3-03-in-ubuntu-linux-distributions)